# How does one retroactively change the bounds of a tkinter Spinbox instance?

Tags: python, tkinter, overwrite, bounds, spinbox

For my program I need to change the list of acceptable values based on updated information from the user.  Is there any method to do that, or a property I can overwrite?

I tried simply:

```
col_spinbox.values = spin_vals
```

where spin_vals is the tuple of values I want, and col_spinbox is the instance for which I'm trying to overwrite the accepted values.  But this didn't work.

From investigation it seems that the property values is stored as a string with spaces in between each value.  So I formatted spin_vals that way, and it still didn't work.  Is there a method that is intended to be used or is there just no way of overwriting the acceptable values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way to change the properties or options of a tkinter widget is to use the universal [`config()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method — and doing this to a `Spinbox`'s `values` option does indeed work.

Simple example.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, values=('red', 'blue', 'green'))
spinbox.pack()

def new_values(spinbox):
    spinbox.config(values=('yellow', 'cyan', 'magenta'))

chg_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Chg", command=lambda: new_values(spinbox))
chg_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```